# try building with their Apportable SDK

Tags: android, ios, cross-compiling, apportable

I haven't used Apportable before. I have used to download their free SDK and i have successfully installed their SDK but no longer to found Apportable folder anywhere.I got the message after i got install,terminal message is given below:

```
 Toolchain downloaded into /Users/Stalin/.apportable/toolchain.
    mv: rename dt to apportable: No such file or directory
    Apportable CLI is successfully installed at /Users/Stalin/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable
    If you're using the default shell, add the Apportable CLI to your PATH using:
    (echo; echo 'PATH="/Users/Stalin/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"') >> ~/.bash_profile; source          ~/.bash_profile
```

I didn't understand this word, apportable should always be run from the same directory as your Xcode project. 
It would be greatfull if you give more information.
Help me, I stuck with start with apportable.

Comment: have you checked cd to /Users/Stalin/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable ?

Comment: I found apportable SDK by below code.

mac6:SDK Stalin$ cd ~/.apportable/
mac6:.apportable Stalin$ ls
SDK  toolchain
 
The Apportable SDK build system is invoked via a command-line interface: apportable. This should always be run from the same directory as your Xcode project.

Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apportable SDK,just using common sense here, The error itself is giving the directions. after installing the sdk you need to set your PATH environmental variable to the Apport SDK path which is   /Users/Stalin/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable after this you will be able to invoke this apport build system from any directory so you can cd to the project directory and invoke the apport build in that directory

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the latest version of the archive, it isn't you and you aren't doing something wrong.

I just issued the apportable update command to get the lastest only to discover that the latest release build is damaged. The file is missing and as such, due to the way the install script works, you, me nor anyone else has a working version of apportable. Hopefully someone catches this and fixes it soon!

Comment: that is because the apportable command was not installed. it is broken for everyone. This just happened within the last couple of hours. Email apportable.

"mv: rename dt to apportable: No such file or directory" - the file "dt" was not in the archive; it is a python script that gets renamed to 'apportable'...understand now?

Comment: A hot fix was pushed last night - so apportable update should now resolve the issue.